# Finding components 'inside' ui:repeat

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to get the child elements of a `UIRepeat`, which i expect to contain all the iterated content. However, instead I only see the contents of one iteration.

I guess I would have to iterate through the `com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat` object, but how to do that? I see there's a `getSize()` function, but `setIndex()` is `private`, and the `DataModel` contains the objects, not the elements.

Also I can't find the `com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat` class in the reference documentation: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html .

The main problem is that I have been displaying `<h:selectOneRadio>` elements iteratively with `<ui:repeat>`; I want to change the value of `<h:selectOneRadio>` elements from a managed bean.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to change the value of `<h:selectOneRadio>` elements from a managed bean.

Just access directly its `value` property from inside the managed bean.

Assuming

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.radios}" var="radio">
    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{radio.selected}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{radio.selectItems}" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
<ui:repeat>
```

just do

```
radios.get(index).setSelected(newValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't now your code or needs, but instead of repeat you could try the c:forEach. The latter works in another rendering phase: the forEach repeats the html content inside the forEach block, while the repeat actually repeats the xhtml content (which is then rendered).